# Stuck In First Epoch When Training CNN model in google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I created a model to identify plant diseases. I expected to identify 10 diseases. in jupyter notebook, it worked fine but it was slow due to GPU constraints. Then I decided to run that model in google colab but it did not run. it stuck at the first epoch.

**The code I use to construct the model is given below**

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
IMAGE_SIZE = 256
CHANNELS=3
EPOCHS=10

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/MyDrive/google-colab-files/PlantVillage",
    seed=123,
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

```
def get_dataset_partisions_tf(ds,trains_split=0.8,val_split=0.1,test_split=0.1,shuffle=True,shuffle_size=10000):
    
    ds_size = len(ds)
    
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size,seed=12)
    
    train_size = int(trains_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)
    
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)
    
    val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)
    
    return train_ds,val_ds,test_ds
```

```
 train_ds,val_ds,test_ds = get_dataset_partisions_tf(dataset)
```

```
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

```
resize_and_rescales = Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])
```

```
data_agmetation = Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal_and_vertical'),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
])
```

```
input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,CHANNELS)
n_classes = 10

model = Sequential([
    resize_and_rescales,
    data_agmetation,
    
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu',input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
])

model.build(input_shape = input_shape)
```

```
model.summary()
```

**A screenshot of the model summary is:**

[image]

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

**When I use the following code to train data:**

```
model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose=2,
    validation_data=val_ds
)
```

**it keeps stuck in the first epoch**

[image]

Comment: It will take some time. Just wait.

Answer (score 0):

Check if TensorFlow is using a GPU or not. You can try reducing batch size.

Answer (score 0):

my assumption is that this is because of your verbose, you should set verbose to 1 to see the step of the epoch you are in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to load your data in the colab space rather than accessing them from drive. You can zip the folder, copy to local space (in colab), unzip it and direct your path to this local space. Still the first epoch could take longer, however, the running time will keep improving for the later epochs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, while training a CNN from section 8.3 of [Chollet's book](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Deep_Learning_with_Python_Second_Edition/XHpKEAAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=chollet%20deep%20learning&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover), using Google Colab with free T4 GPU and storing data on Google Drive. The dataset includes 2,000 images for training, 1,000 for validation and 2,000 for testing.

My solution was not to use `image_dataset_from_directory` in the first place.

With `image_dataset_from_directory` the first epoch took **5 to 10 minutes** to execute, while the following epochs executed in the order of few **tens of seconds** (10-20s).
By manually loading the dataset from Google Drive, using `load_img` and `img_to_array`, and directly storing it in memory — which is possible with a small dataset like the above — it took **1 minute** to first load the images into numpy arrays, and then all epochs, including the first one, executed in few **tens of seconds**.

So in my case it was clearly advantegous to go manually.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

input_dir = "drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dogs-vs-cats-small"

def get_images(images_dir):
  num_images = len(os.listdir(images_dir))
  image_size = (180,180)
  images = np.zeros((num_images,)+image_size+(3,))
  for i, fn in enumerate(os.listdir(images_dir)):
    img = keras.utils.load_img(
        f"{images_dir}/{fn}",
        target_size=image_size,
        interpolation='bilinear')
    img = keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    images[i] = img
  return np.array(images)

def get_dataset(dataset_dir):
  data_dogs = get_images(f"{dataset_dir}/dogs")
  data_cats = get_images(f"{dataset_dir}/cats")
  return (
      np.concatenate((data_dogs, data_cats)),
      np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(data_dogs)), np.ones(len(data_cats))))
      )

train_data, train_targets = get_dataset(f"{input_dir}/train/")
print(f"Loaded train dataset: {train_data.shape}, {train_targets.shape}")
validation_data, validation_targets = get_dataset(f"{input_dir}/validation/")
print(f"Loaded validation dataset: {validation_data.shape}, {validation_targets.shape}")
test_data, test_targets = get_dataset(f"{input_dir}/test/")
print(f"Loaded test dataset: {test_data.shape}, {test_targets.shape}")
```